# How can I count expiration date in Grails, if I know the amount of time left?

Tags: grails, groovy, time, duration, content-expiration

I want to insert expiration date in Redis based on TTL.
How can I count the expiration date?

I'm trying to use `TimeCategory` class, here is the example:

```
def ttl = 3600;
def date = new Date()

TimeDuration duration = getSeconds(ttl) 

TimeDuration expiryDate = date.plus.duration
```

Is that a correct approach to expiry date counting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overcomplicated if you ask me.

One-liner should be sufficient here:

```
Date expiryDate = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + ttlInSeconds * 1000l )
```

Make sure you are using `long` numbers here, otherwise the numbers will be cut down to `2147483647` which might lead to wrong results for large TTLs.

Comment: should I import groovy time: `import groovy.time.*` ?

Comment: no additional imports needed, it's plain `java.util`

Comment: will this solution also work with seconds? cause `ttl` is the amount of second and I could see you used `currentTimeMillis()` method

Comment: it is counting, but shows a wrong data, for ex. if `ttl = 13140000` (5 month), the expiry date shows:
Mon Apr 08 11:07:37 EEST 2019

Comment: it's because you use `int` by default instead of `long`. then it would give you `Wed Sep 04 11:19:26 GMT 2019`. See the update

Comment: Everything is working! Thank you very much! Can you explain please, why it didn't work with `int` but worked with `long` - the amount of number exceeds `int` length?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` == `2147483647`, so if the inteded value is greater then that, it would be cut down.